# How do I get return values from a boost thread?

Tags: c++, boost

I want to do something simple like

```
void returnVal(int a, int &b)
{
    b = a;
}

int main()
{
    int b = 0;
    boost::thread t(returnVal,1,b);
    t.join();
}
```

This throws errors. Cannot convert int& to int. There must be a simple way to get return values in boost, and if there is not does anyone have a decent explanation as to why?

Comment: What would be the return value of that function? `a`? And you want to retrieve it by reading `b` afterwards?

Comment: You pass arguments into a thread via boost::promise or boost::packaged_task and to get the result you use boost::future. (Or for simpler use use boot::async)

Answer (score 2):

`boost::thread` constructor uses `boost::bind`. boost::bind takes its arguments by copy default, so

`b = a;`

modifies copy of `b` from main. You need to use `boost::ref()` to pass reference to `b` into `thread`:

```
boost::thread t(returnVal,1,boost::ref(b));
```

Comment: ahhh I need to add -lboost_ref in order for this to work?

Comment: no , you need to link with `boost_thread` and i suppose `thread_system` as well. There is no boost_ref library. [DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/666a948069ce2e6e)